# How to open the different excel sheets based on the array input in java

Tags: java

I have got the values from excel called ReadScenario.xls in an arraylist (lnpResultList). How to open the different excel sheets based on the input which i have got. Below is ReadScenario.xls

TestCase    1    2       3         4        5   6   7   8   9   10
TC1       Login  Create  Find      Activity
TC2       Login  Find    Activity  Report
TC3       Find   Activity
TC4       Create Report

My output is : [TC2, Login, Find, Activity, Report, null, null, null, null, null, null]
I have different excel sheets for Login,Find,etc.
From the above I need open Login excel.How to do that?
Below is my code:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import resources.fg_ReadPageHelper;
import com.rational.test.ft.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.SAP.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.WPF.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.dojo.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.siebel.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.flex.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.generichtmlsubdomain.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.script.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.value.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.vp.*;
import com.ibm.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.sapwebportal.*;
/**
 * Description   : Functional Test Script
 * @author IBM
 */
public class fg_ReadPage extends fg_ReadPageHelper
{
    /**
     * Script Name   : <b>fg_ReadPage</b>
     * Generated     : <b>Apr 3, 2017 5:01:09 PM</b>
     * Description   : Functional Test Script
     * Original Host : WinNT Version 6.1  Build 7601 (S)
     * 
     * @since  2017/04/03
     * @author IBM
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public void testMain(Object[] args) throws SQLException 
    {
        // TODO Insert code here
        String Filename = "C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/ReadScenario.xls";
        Statement stmt = ConnectionwithExcel.OpenConnection(Filename);
        String query = "select * from [Scenario$] where [TestCase]= 'TC2';";
        ResultSet results = ConnectionwithExcel.OpenRecordset(stmt, query);

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = results.getMetaData(); 
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        ArrayList<String> lnpResultList = new ArrayList<>(columnCount);
        while (results.next()) {              
           int i = 1;
           while(i <= columnCount) {
                lnpResultList.add(results.getString(i++));
           }
        } 

        System.out.println(lnpResultList);


/*      while( rs.next() )// when we don't know how many iterations//ResultSet object can be moved forward only and it is not updateable
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name")+ " " +rs.getInt("id"));
            String ctrlName = rs.getString(2);
            //rs.getArray("TC1);
        //When id =3 ;No rows found should come--//
        }*/
        ConnectionwithExcel.CloseStatement();
        ConnectionwithExcel.CloseConnection();


    }
}
```